Title: Spring Boot API Endpoint Returning 404 Not Found for Registration Request (no databases)
I'm developing a web application deployed on Azure. The registration endpoint of my API is returning a 404 Not Found error when accessed from the frontend. The backend is set up to handle registration requests, and the frontend is correctly configured to send the registration data.
this is the java controller
it also returns a 404 when deployed on a localhost. (ive checked if the endpoints are correct yes)
the end goal for me is so my login works (deployed on azure) and not just localhost if i even get that to work
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody User newUser) {
        User registeredUser = userService.registerUser(newUser.getPhoneNumber(), newUser.getUsername(), newUser.getPassword());
        if (registeredUser != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Registration successful");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Registration failed");
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> loginUser(@RequestBody User loginUser, HttpSession session) {
        User user = userService.loginUser(loginUser.getUsername(), loginUser.getPassword());
        if (user != null) {
            session.setAttribute("userId", user.getUserId());
            Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("message", "Login successful");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
        } else {
            Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("message", "Invalid credentials");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(response);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logoutUser(HttpSession session) {
        session.invalidate();
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("message", "Logged out successfully");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testEndpoint() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Test endpoint is working!");
    }
}


public class UserService {
    private UserData userData = new UserData();

    public User registerUser(String phoneNumber, String username, String password) {
        return userData.registerUser(phoneNumber, username, password);
    }

    public User getUserById(String userId) {
        return userData.getUserById(userId);
    }

    public User loginUser(String username, String password) {
        return userData.loginUser(username, password);
    }
}


package Backend;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User {
    private String userId;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private List<User> friends;

    public User(String userId, String phoneNumber, String username, String password, List<User> friends) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    // Getters and setters
}


document.getElementById('registerForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    let phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phonenumber').value;

    var userData = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/users/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(userData)
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            alert('Registration successful!');
            document.getElementById('registerForm').reset();
            window.location.href = 'login.html';
        } else {
            throw new Error('Registration failed.');
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Registration error:', error);
        alert('Registration failed. Please try again later.');
    });
});


Issue:
When I try to submit the registration form, I receive a 404 Not Found error. I have verified that my API is correctly deployed on Azure and should be accessible
I have:
Ensured that the Azure app service is running.
Verified that the endpoint /api/users/register is correctly defined in UserController.java.
Checked the CORS configuration in WebConfig.java to allow requests from all origins.
Confirmed that the JavaScript file (Register.js) is correctly linked and making a POST request to the correct Azure URL.
Edit:
everything works fine locally, and my frontend is made with plain html/css/js
the links ids and names are also linked correctly
Edit:
my html css and js are all in a static file,
src/main/resources/static/ccs
src/main/resources/static/js
src/main/resources/static/(all my html code)

What is your Frontend Framework?

Is your web app working fine locally?

Dorrestijn Are you including your Frontend in Static Files of Spring boot app or deploying your frontend separately to azure web app.

I tried below code and deployed to the azure app service without any issues.
Make sure that frontend's fetch Uri is matches the Azure web app uri endpoint
https://<Azurewebappurl>/api/users/register
and Cors is configured to allow request from all origins in webConfig.java.
Below is the complete code for registration.
register.js:
document.getElementById('registerForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    let phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phonenumber').value;
    var userData = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber
    };
    fetch('/api/users/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(userData)
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            alert('Registration successful!');
            document.getElementById('registerForm').reset();
            window.location.href = 'login.html';
        } else {
            throw new Error('Registration failed.');
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Registration error:', error);
        alert('Registration failed. Please try again later.');
    });
});

register.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="registerForm">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>

        <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" required><br>

        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/js/register.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

webConfig.java:
package com.example.myapp.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*") 
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
}

Azure Web App Output:



